# Find any line in VI that has something other than ATCG

Tags: linux, text-processing, vi, bioinformatics

I have a file of genomic data that is approximately 5 million lines long and should have only the characters A, T, C, and G in it. The problem is, I know how large the file should be, but it's slightly larger than that. Which means, something went wrong in an analysis, or there are lines that contain something other than genomic data.

Is there a way to find any line that has something other than an A, T, C, or G? Due to the nature of the file, any other letter, spaces, numbers, symbols shouldn't be present. I've gone through searching symbol by symbol, so I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be in vi? Maybe grep -e "[^ATCG]" also works?

Comment: Is each like one column, or four columns with A, T, C and G in any order?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, you definitely do not want to open the file in an editor (it's much too large to edit that way).

Instead, if you just want to *identify* whether the file contains anything other than `A`, `T`, `C` and `G`, you may do that with

```
grep '[^ATCG]' filename
```

This would return all lines that contain anything other than those four characters.

If you would want to *delete* these characters from the file, you may do so with

```
tr -c -d 'ATCG\n' <filename >newfilename
```

(if this is the correct way to "correct" the file or not, I don't know)

This would remove all characters in the file that are not one of the four, and it would also retain newlines (`\n`).  The edited file would be written to `newfilename`.

If it's a systematic error that has added something to the file, then this could possibly be corrected by `sed` or `awk`, but we don't yet know what your data looks like.

---

If you have the file open in `vi` or `vim`, then the command

```
/[^ATCG]
```

will find the next character in the editing buffer that is not a `A`, `T`, `C` or `G`.

And `:%s/[^ATCG]//g` will remove them all.

Comment: the `--line-number` (`-n`) argument to grep could be useful for obvious reasons

Comment: Doesn't `grep '[^ATCG]'` just look for A, T, C & G in *the first column*?

Comment: @RonJohn No.  The `^` has a totally different meaning when it occurs as the first character within `[...]` (it negates the character class).

Comment: I knew I should have added "not"... :)  Thus, doesn't `grep '[^ATCG]'` look for any row which does *not* have A, T, C & G *in the first column*?

Comment: @RonJohn No. It looks for lines of text where at least one character is not `A`, `T`, `C` or `G`.  The `[...]` means "one of these characters", and with the `^` at the start of that group, it means "a character, but _not_ one of these".

Answer (score 0):

I focused on the title

> Find any line in VI that has something other than ATCG

And I tested this from VI editor so called "last line mode".

`:%!tr -c -d 'ATCG\n`

`:` enters command-line mode, `%` matches whole file as a range, `!` filters that range through an external command `tr -c -d 'ATCG\n` that happens to be the same as @Kusalananda wrote :).